# AutoPostBack on asp:BulletedList to get selectedValue in PageLoad

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following DropDownList:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ssbl" runat="server" 
        DisplayMode="LinkButton" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ApplyFilter"
        AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

This works well; On select, the page posts back and the value of the selected item is available during PageLoad.

What I want is the pretty much exact same list just not displayed as a dropdown list that will also make the selected value available during PageLoad. When i create a bulletedList control and set an onClick event (AutoPostBack is not a property for a BulletedList), the selected value is not available during pageload.

Is there a different control that can be used that replicates the functionality of a DropDownList but just displays the list differently?

Comment: Check out [RadioButtonList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: are you using any `if(IsPostBack)` code in your Page_Load Code behind..? perhaps you may need to do some javascript can  you show the code behind code

Comment: Any control in a page can have an event tied to it for a postback.  Just set the onClick event to call a function in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a RadioButtonList as suggested in the comments and using CSS to hide the bullets. Seemed to be a little easier than the DataList control and ListBox didn't give me as much control over the design as I would like.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control. It behaves *exactly* like dropdown control (`AutoPostBack`, `OnSelectedIndexChanged`) - but displays all items as a list.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ssbl" runat="server"
   DisplayMode="LinkButton"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ApplyFilter"
    AutoPostBack="true">

    <asp:ListItem>aaaaaaaaaa</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>bbbbbbbbbb</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>cccccccccc</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>dddddddddd</asp:ListItem>

</asp:ListBox>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I played around with this, but is there a control that would  render the list in a <ul> instead of in <opton>? I need it displayed as a horizontal list

Comment: Ok, for a more granular control consider DataList control - it lets you specify exactly how you want items to look (including direction - horizontal or vertical)